# Quotient and Remainder of Numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

May I ask what is the logic behind the quotient and remainder for numbers in such situation.

```
  n      = q x d + r 
  11 / 5 = 2 x 5 + 1    (Therefore, quotient is 2, and the remainder is 1)

  However, when we have a negative value,

  -11 / 5 = -3 x 5 + 4 (The quotient becomes -3 even though it shows 2 in the calculator)
```

Can I safely say that whenever there is a negative number as the result (-11 in this case, the quotient and remainder will be different from what we see on the calculators? (eg. -11 / 5 = 2.2)?

Comment: Yes, expect the case that the quotient is an integer, if what you meant by the calculator is taking the integer part of the answer. Remember by definition the remainder is a positive number between $0$ and the absolute value of divisor.

Comment: People who do Number Theory want the remainder to be at least zero and less than the absolute value of the divisor. People who design calculators may have different desiderata. Similarly, the integer part of $-\pi$ is $-4$ according to math, but $-3$ according to many calculators.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ and $d$ be integers with $d \neq 0$.  When we write 
$$n = qd + r$$
it is usually understood that $0 \leq r < |d|$.

Since 
$$11 = 2 \cdot 5 + 1$$
we obtain
$$\frac{11}{5} = \frac{2 \cdot 5 + 1}{5} = \frac{2 \cdot 5}{5} + \frac{1}{5} = 2 + 0.2 = 2.2$$

Using division with remainder yields 
$$-11 = -3 \cdot 5 + 4$$
Thus,
$$-\frac{11}{5} = \frac{-3 \cdot 5 + 4}{5} = -\frac{3 \cdot 5}{5} + \frac{4}{5} = -3 + 0.8 = -2.2$$
However, it is sometimes convenient to use negative remainders.  We can simply change each sign in the equation $11 = 2 \cdot 5 + 1$ to obtain
$$-11 = -2 \cdot 5 - 1$$
so
$$-\frac{11}{5} = \frac{-2 \cdot 5 - 1}{5} = -\frac{2 \cdot 5}{5} - \frac{1}{5} = -2 - 0.2 = -2.2$$
Using positive or negative remainders leads to the same result.

When we write $2.2$, the integer part of $2.2$ is $\lfloor 2.2 \rfloor = 2$, the greatest integer less than $2.2$.  On the other hand, the integer part of  $-2.2$ is $\lceil -2.2 \rceil = -2$, the least integer greater than $-2.2$.

More generally, the integer part of any nonnegative real number expressed in decimal form $x$ is $\lfloor x \rfloor$, the greatest integer less than $x$, while the integer part of any negative real number expressed in decimal form is $\lceil x \rceil$, the least integer greater than $x$.

What your calculator shows you is the quotient plus the remainder expressed in decimal form, so $-3 + 0.8$ is expressed as $-2.2$.